# C# Selenium how to click a button on an extension?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i want to click a button on an extension. But i don't know about how can i do it. I couldn't find any source for it. Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236141/how-to-manipulate-chrome-extensions-widget-with-selenium-or-another-tool) solution for the **C#**, I hope this will work for you as well.

In case you are coding with **Python** this should work for you:
This can be done with use of `pyautogui` tool.
Install `pyautogui`, then get the image of the extension icon and save it on your computer in some location like `./icon.png`.
Now you will be able to click on the extension as following:

```py
import pyautogui

img_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('./icon.png', confidence=0.5)
image_location_point = pyautogui.center(img_location)
x, y = image_location_point
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Credits to the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719005/3485434)

Comment: is pyautogui available for c#? Am using c# with selenium

Comment: I see, please see if C# solution worked for you

Comment: _pyautogui_ is a _Py(Python)_ library.

Comment: I made a mistake and then corrected myself. So I mentioned a link to C# solution in the first part for the OP and added a Python solution after that since most Selenium users are working with Python these days